# Oracle SQL: missing expression error on UNION clause

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN connect_by_isleaf = 1 THEN 0
        WHEN level = 1             THEN 1
        ELSE                           -1
   END AS status, 
   level, 
   name AS title, 
   NULL AS icon, 
   child_id   AS value, 
   NULL AS tooltip, 
   NULL AS link 
FROM (
   SELECT alu.arl_user_user_id AS child_id,
          alu.arl_list_list_id AS parent_id,
          '0'                  AS type,
         emp.employee_name    AS name
    FROM arl_list_user alu
    INNER JOIN arl_user au
            ON au.user_id = alu.arl_user_user_id
    INNER JOIN arl_active_emp emp
            ON au.arl_active_employee_id = emp.employee_id
  UNION
  SELECT all.arl_list_list_id  AS child_id,
         all.arl_list_list_id1 AS parent_id,
         '1'                   AS type,
         al.name               AS name
    FROM arl_list_list all
    INNER JOIN arl_list al
            ON al.list_id = all.arl_list_list_id
) table
START WITH child_id IN (
  SELECT child_id
    FROM table
    WHERE type = '1'
)
CONNECT BY PRIOR child_id = parent_id
```

This results in a parse error:

> ORA-06550: line 21, column 1: ORA-00936: missing expression.

I've done some googling and it looks like "missing expression" usually means that the query is missing a FROM clause somewhere or, in the case of a UNION, the two unioned queries don't have the same number of columns.  I'm fairly sure that neither is the case here, and I can't figure out what the real problem is.

Comment: You have aliased your inner select `table`, which is a reserved keyword because you can select from a table type (hence the missing clauses). You don't use the alias so remove it.

Comment: Where is `connect_by_isleaf` coming from?

Comment: I would try running the inner (`UNION`) query on its own to see if you get the same error.

Comment: @PhilWalton: that's an Oracle built-in function: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns001.htm#SQLRF50940

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Oops, my mind's eye had put an `as` in that row.  Deleted my comment.

Comment: Also, `ALL` is a reserved word, not sure if it causes the problem here or not, but I'd rather avoid using it as an identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use `all` and `table` (and many other reserved words) as table, column or subquery aliases...